# How can I gain access to the contents of my password-protected RAR files?

Tags: backup, restore

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. Before upgrading it i backup my files and when I installed and upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.04 I tried to restore my files but they were in password-encrypted rar files and I forgot the password.

I searched in web and tried many windows applications through Wine. But error messages flashed "deficiency in wine." So I searched the web for Ubuntu softwares and found John the Ripper but the problem is, I don't understand how to use it. And I am not aware of how to browse the directories from terminal.

Comment: Breaking winrar password is almost impossible practically .. it takes too much resources and too many days

Comment: @Web-E Doesn't that depend a lot on how strong of a password the archive is encrypted with? (Also, doesn't GPU computation decrease the time significantly, sometimes?)

Comment: well if the information is important enough then the day spending breaking the key might just be worth it, so how would one do it then?

Comment: @user135738 Have you tried [RarCrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can browse directories using `cd <directory_name>\<inside_directory_name>` in terminal. Or just type `cd` and some initial letter (case sensitive), then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete folder name.

Try this software

http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/

All instructions are given in page, I am writing from it for any fureture references, 
Save the package to a location, say `Downloads`.

Open up a terminal, type `cd Downloads` (we are changing to Downloads directory)

execute `tar -xjf rarcrack-0.2.tar.bz2` → this will extract the files.

Get into the extracted folder, execute `cd rarcrack-0.2`

Compile the program, execute `make`

Install the program by executing `sudo make install`

Now this program is installed.

**Usage**

Open a terminal, use `cd` to goto directory where you file is stored. say named `abc.rar`

run `rarcrack abc.rar --threads <thread_num> --type rar`

Provide a numeric value instead of **thread_num**. This is number of threads. If you have multicore processor use it. A simple rule like, 2x no of core in your system. Like quad core i7, provide thread number as 8. Increasing this number to a greater value may cause system hang.

Once completed, started the rar crack will create an xml file  in same directory with current password. You can stop the tool and modify the xml to define the character set to be searched next time you run the tool.

**As I told earlier, it takes long time to break a password. To check for a 5 character long  alpha-numaric password (no upper case), will take around 13 days if the tool process 50 keys/sec.**

More technical details if you are interested - http://anrieff.net/ucbench/technical_qna.html

Comment: you can accept the answer by clicking the green tick on top left corner